# Copying files into the application folder at compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I have some files I want to copy from my project into the `.\bin\debug\` folder on compilation, then it seems I have to put them into the root of the project. Putting them into a subfolder seems to copy them into the `.\bin\debug\` folder in the same structure they're stored in.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Just to be clear: if I have a `MyFirstConfigFile.txt` and `MySecondConfigFile.txt` in a `ConfigFiles` folder and I set their *Copy to Output* to be *Copy...*, then they appear in the `.\bin\debug\ConfigFiles\` folder.  I want them to appear in the `.\bin\debug\` folder.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You could do this with a post build event. Set the files to no action on compile, then in the macro copy the files to the directory you want.

Here's a post build Macro that I think will work by copying all files in a directory called Configuration to the root build folder:

```
copy $(ProjectDir)Configuration\* $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)
```

Comment: For the destination, shouldn't it be $(ProjectDir)\%(OutDir)?

Comment: Correct and tested (Vs2010) macro is: copy "$(ProjectDir)Firebird\firebird_bin\*" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"

Comment: You can also just do a relative file for output: copy "$(ProjectDir)Firebird\firebird_bin*" "$(OutDir)"

Comment: so how do you know what's injected for $(ProjectDir) is it an absolute or relative path and to what?

Comment: I think that the use of quotes is necessary:
`copy "$(ProjectDir)subfolder_name\"* "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"`

Comment: I have tried postBuild events many times before and i recommend the MSBuild task approach over it because it has an option to ignore errors. see the answer by @jhonny-d-cano-leftware

Comment: In MSVS2017 (15.4) it should just be `$(OutDir)` (i.e. without `$(ProjectDir)`) it seems... else you get double path errors

Answer (score 60):

You can use a MSBuild task on your csproj, like that.

Edit your csproj file

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)yourfiles" DestinationFolder="$(YourVariable)" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: This is the best solution as you can use wildcards to copy many files, and they don't need to be in the project.

Answer (score 48):

You can also put the files or links into the root of the solution explorer and then set the files properties:

`Build action = Content`

and

`Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer` (for example)

For a link drag the file from the windows explorer into the solution explorer holding down the shift and control keys.

[image]

Comment: This will preserve the original relative path, which isn't acceptable to the OP

Comment: If you put the file into the top level node of your project, then it will be copied directly into the output folder $(OutputPath).

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743907/visual-studio-how-to-copy-to-output-directory-without-copying-the-folder-stru) for an acceptable alternative

Answer (score 33):

Personally I prefer this way.

Modify the `.csproj` to add

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="ConfigFiles\MyFirstConfigFile.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

or generalizing, if you want to copy all subfolders and files, you could do:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="ConfigFiles\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: In my opinion way better than a post-build event event. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this just the same as right-clicking the project and selecting "Add | Existing Item" from Solution Explorer, then setting the File property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer". There's no need to modify the XML directly.

Comment: @AntonyBooth after a while you'll realize it's always easier to understand what's going on and modify the code directly rather than learning how to do the same thing with your IDE. Today you're using Visual Studio, tomorrow it might be JetBrains Rider and the day after tomorrow VS Code. At the end, you're always better mastering a language rather than an IDE. PS: I don't know if what you describe is the same since I only know how to do it in XML, much better like this.

Comment: Additionally, there's no way currently to set the target path within the IDE, so for now we have to edit the XML.

Answer (score 3):

copy from subfolder to subfolder

```
 if not exist "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)subfolder" mkdir "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)subfolder"

 copy "$(ProjectDir)subfolder\"  "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)subfolder\"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for contributing. You've answered a really old question that already has a bunch of highly upvoted answers. If you think your answer is useful to have in addition to the existing upvoted answers, you should add a little explanation for why your answer solves the problem and why it's better/different from the others.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a solution I've tried a command
"xcopy /y $(ProjectDir)yourfile  $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)" but it is not OS agnostic, so I faced problems when it executed on Linux.

I tried this instead. It is operational systems agnostic:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="YourFolderHere\*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Try use this : is not enough. You need to provide an explanation for the content you've shared in your response.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a Post-Build event on your project.  You can specify the output there and there are macro values for frequently used things like project path, item name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PostBuild event of the project. After the build is completed, you can run a DOS batch file and copy the desired files to your desired folder.

Answer (score -1):

I found this question searching for "copy files into the application folder at compile time". OP seems to have this sorted already, but if you don't:

In Visual Studio right-click the file, select properties, then change the option 'copy to output' to 'always'. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx

Comment: OP asks for copying to compile directory without keeping the relative directory structure of the copied file location