# Create a folder after build using project.json in NET Core

Tags: c#, json, angular, asp.net-core, project.json

I know you can use "copyToOutput" in project.json to copy files to a project's output directory, but is it possible to copy over an entire folder?

Comment: You can use post build event as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747941/copying-files-into-the-application-folder-at-compile-time

Answer (score 1):

You can add directories just the way you add files. Note that empty directories will be ignored using this approach.

```
"buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [ "someFile.json", "myDirectory" ],
    }
  }
```