# Not able to read data files outside of bin\debug directory

Tags: c#

I'm writing a unit test that reads data from a json file. Currently the directories are like this:

```
Unit test: ..\Source\Repos\ReposName\Project.Tests\MyUnitTest.cs
Test data: ..\Source\Repos\ReposName\Project.Tests\testData\testData.json
```

Now in my unit test, I'm trying to read the testData.json into a string that can be deserialized into my collection object.

```
string testDataFolder = "testData";
string jsonFileName = "testData.json";
string testJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, testDataFolder, jsonFileName));
```

When I run the unit test, I keep getting an error complaining that my testData.json is not located in the `\bin\debug\netcoreapp3.1` location. I don't understand why `File.ReadAllText()` keeps looking in that location when I'm telling it to just look in my `\Source\Repos\ReposName\Project.Tests\testData` folder. Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this correctly? I must be missing something here. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying files into the application folder at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747941/copying-files-into-the-application-folder-at-compile-time)

Comment: That's a good start. I'll dig into this more. Thank you.